# How to raise Datagrid RowEditEnding event from seperate window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid

I have two separate windows in my WPF project , the first one contains a `DataGrid` and the second one contains some controls and an ok button .

What i want is when i click on the ok button , the `RowEditEnding` event of the `DataGrid` which is in the second window will be raised. Any idea please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but why would you like to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A window can't raise the `RowEditEnding` of the `DataGrid`. It can only handle it. Only the `DataGrid` itself can actually raise the event.

If you move the code that you have written in the event handler to a standalone method, you can simply call this from the other window. You will need to get a reference to the window where the `DataGrid` is defined first.

Please refer to the following sample code.

**Window 1:**

```
private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    HandleEvent();
}

public void HandleEvent()
{
    //your logic...
}
```

**Window 2:**

```
Window1 win = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window1>().FirstOrDefault();
if (win != null)
    win.HandleEvent();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Window2 win = new Window2();
  win.Show();
  win.MyGrid.RaiseEvent(new RowEditEnding(sender,e));
}
```

Comment: window2 already instantiated even before window1 , so if we instantiate a new window2 we will lose the cell values of the datagrid..

Comment: ok then just get the window2 object then raise evenet of window2 grid

Comment: how can i get it ?

Comment: as you said windows2 is already instantiated then did you have its object right?

Comment: window2 is a user control , it will be instantiated automatically when the application starts